# How to read data file from client machine in wan

Tags: javascript, html, file-read

Is there any way to read the contents of a text file from a client browser? For example, I would like to let the user click on a button to place the contents of `C:\cmd.txt` into an html element for view.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible without user consent (I hope!!!). A website can not read a file on the client machine without asking the user. Think of all the security risks it would imply if it could...

Your solution could be to ask the user which file to open and then have them select the c:\cmd.txt file. After that, reading the file is easy.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@Rick van den Bosh is correct as to your basic options using native HTML and javascript.

The only additional options would be a Java applet or browser plugin. However, your users would have to trust you enough to install your control, and savvy users aren't going to do that unless you are a major site like amazon.com or cvs.com or some well-known commercial enterprise.